# select one or multiple Donor IDs to plot graph in shiny in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

My Shiny application allows users to select one or multiple Donor IDs by using:

```
selectizeInput("donor", label = "Enter Donor ID:", 
                                               choices = as.list(c(unique(df$ID))), 
                                               multiple = TRUE,
                                               options = list(),
                                               selected = NULL)
```

The selected IDs will be stored in the input$donor variable.  If no donor IDs are selected (input$donor is null), mapping the color aesthetic to the x variable (input$x_var2), and using the color_code function to determine the color values. This boxplot (as shown below) is default to show in the first place if user doesn't input anything in input$donor:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("ID0001", "ID0002", "ID0003", "ID0004", "ID0005"),
  Gender = c("Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female"),
  AgeGroup = c("30yr_39yr", "40yr_49yr", "40yr_49yr", "30yr_39yr", "30yr_39yr"),
  variable1 = c(10, 12, 8, 15, 11),
  variable2 = c(5, 3, 7, 9, 6),
  variable3 = c(20, 18, 22, 17, 19)
)

color_code <- function(x) {
  switch(x,
         Gender = c("#ff0000", "#4472c4"),
         AgeGroup = c("20yr_29yr" = "#c5e0b4", 
                      "30yr_39yr" = "#b4c7e7", 
                      "40yr_49yr" = "#f8cbad", 
                      "50yr_59yr" = "#c55a11", 
                      "60yr_69yr" = "#bf9000", 
                      "70yr_80yr" = "#7030a0"
         ),
         NULL
  )
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = !!sym(input$x_var2), y = !!sym(input$y_var2))) +
        theme_bw() +
        # coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges$x, ylim = ranges$y, expand = TRUE) +
        geom_boxplot(color = "black", fill = "white", width = 0.5, size = 1.0, outlier.shape = NA, coef = 1.5) +
        geom_jitter(aes(color = !!sym(input$x_var2)), width = 0.1, alpha = 0.5) +
        scale_color_manual(values = color_code(input$x_var2))
```

But it's crashed when I add the condition for change the boxplot to map the color aesthetic to the selected points. What i would like to do is, if input$donor is not null, the boxplot changes the color aesthetic based on selected points in input$donor (i.e. only the selected donor show the red point, the remaining unselected donor are black in boxplot). That's why I create a new column to store the IDs that are selected.

```
ui.R
selectizeInput("donor", label = "Enter Donor ID:", 
                                               choices = as.list(c(unique(df$ID))), 
                                               multiple = TRUE,
                                               options = list(),
                                               selected = NULL)
```

```
server.R

    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    
df$selection <- ifelse(df$ID %in% input$donor, "selected", "unselected") 

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = !!sym(input$x_var2), y = !!sym(input$y_var2))) +
        theme_bw() +
        # coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges$x, ylim = ranges$y, expand = TRUE) +
        geom_boxplot(color = "black", fill = "white", width = 0.5, size = 1.0, outlier.shape = NA, coef = 1.5) +
        # colored by selected IDs in inputbox
        if (!is.null(input$donor)) {
          geom_jitter(df, aes(color = selection), width = 0.1, alpha = 0.5) +
            scale_color_manual(values = c("unselected" = "black", "selected" = "red")) 
         # colored by gender
        } else {
          geom_jitter(df, aes(color = !!sym(input$x_var2)), width = 0.1, alpha = 0.5) +
            scale_color_manual(values = color_code(input$x_var2)) 
        }
       
      p


})
    
    output$brush_info2 <- renderTable({
      brushedPoints(df, input$plot2_brush)
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a real shiny issue. As I recommended in my answer to one of your previous questions put your plotting code in a separate function for easier testing and debugging.

First, instead of `geom_point(df, ...)` use `data = df` or simply drop it as `df` is the global data.

Second, inside an `if` you can no longer add layers together using `+`. Instead, put them in a `list`.

```
library(ggplot2)

input <- list(
  x_var2 = "Gender",
  y_var2 = "variable1",
  donor = NULL
)

df$selection <- ifelse(df$ID %in% input$donor, "selected", "unselected")

ggplot(df, aes(x = !!sym(input$x_var2), y = !!sym(input$y_var2))) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_boxplot(color = "black", fill = "white", width = 0.5, size = 1.0, outlier.shape = NA, coef = 1.5) +
  if (!is.null(input$donor)) {
    list(
      geom_jitter(aes(color = selection), width = 0.1, alpha = 0.5),
      scale_color_manual(values = c("unselected" = "black", "selected" = "red"))  
    )
  } else {
    list(
      geom_jitter(aes(color = !!sym(input$x_var2)), width = 0.1, alpha = 0.5),
      scale_color_manual(values = color_code(input$x_var2))  
    )
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I see. Seems I made a silly mistake lmao. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: Not a silly mistake. These are the issues each one encounters sooner or later. (: BTW: As a reminder. When you get an answer to a question and it helps to solve your issue then it is good practice on SO to accept and/or upvote the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Accepted, thank you for your help!